# Installation elasticsearch 7.8.0 on windows 10 gives error as TempDirectory and JVMParserFailed is not recognized as internal or external command

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana-7, java-13

I downloaded elasticsearch 7.8.0 zip file and unzip that.Using command prompt when I go to bin directory using cd and then type elasticsearch.bat it gives me following error.

Please suggest me appropriate solution.

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.1006]
(c) 2018 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Windows\system32>d:

D:\>cd  D:\Users\Shivani\Downloads\elasticsearch-7.8.0

D:\Users\Shivani\Downloads\elasticsearch-7.8.0>cd bin

D:\Users\Shivani\Downloads\elasticsearch-7.8.0\bin>elasticsearch.bat
'CALL "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.2\bin\java.exe" -cp "D:\Users\Shivani\Downloads\elasticsearch-7.8.0\lib\*" "org.elasticsearch.tools.launchers.TempDirectory"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'CALL "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.2\bin\java.exe" -cp "D:\Users\Shivani\Downloads\elasticsearch-7.8.0\lib\*" "org.elasticsearch.tools.launchers.JvmOptionsParser" "D:\Users\Shivani\Downloads\elasticsearch-7.8.0\config" || echo jvm_options_parser_failed' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

D:\Users\Shivani\Downloads\elasticsearch-7.8.0\bin>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that Elastic 7.8 does not support Jdk 13. Try it with 11 or no jdk at all (It has its own inside the download folder).
https://www.elastic.co/de/support/matrix#matrix_jvm

Comment: Same error is there now I remove JAVA_HOME system variable and used jdk of elasticsearch.or when jdk 11 is used.Is there any windows related problem?I have windows 10 ,64 bit

Comment: No, its not a windows problem. I rund elastic on windows 10, 64 Bit and everything is fine. Did you delete all JAVA_HOME variables and removed it from the path?